# Direct Partial Integration - How do I solve this?

Tags: calculus

I have two questions that I need to work out and I have lost my notes, so I have no idea how to go about solving these:

1. $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2t\cos\theta$ with boundaries of $u=2t$ and $\theta=0$.
2. $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=8e^y\sin2x$ with boundaries of $y=0$, $u=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\sin x$, and $x=2y^2$.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.